# How to make Ctrl+C stop the blocked process `winpty python2 gtk-gui.py` in MSYS2 terminal?

Tags: python-2.7, shell, windows-10, gtk3, msys2

I would like to have a method of closing the process without closing the terminal (shell). I tried Ctrl+C, Ctrl+D and other key combinations and they do not stop the `winpty python2 gtk-gui.py` process. These key combinations I tried do not print anything in the terminal.

I use winpty 0.4.3 and Python 2.7.13 both installed from MSYS2 using the pacman package manager. The reason I use winpty to start Python is because only in this way I have realtime standard output in the terminal, including the standard error stream, because there is a bug in MSYS2 regarding dirty or incomplete output of the Python interpreter.

An example of Python script that produces the problem:

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

window = Gtk.Window()
window.add(Gtk.Label("Closing this window won't close "
                     "the process but it will hide the window. "
                     "How can I kill the process from the shell "
                     "in this situation?"))
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

If I run the script just with this command (without winpty): `python2 gtk-gui.py`, the Ctrl+C key combination works well. I know very well how to make the process to exit normally, but I often get unhandled exceptions that do not stop the process, so I want a way to kill it for debugging purposes.